# How can I add custom gradients in the Haskell autodifferentiation library "ad"?

Tags: haskell, numerical-methods, gradient-descent, autodiff

If I want to give a custom or known gradient for a function, how can I do that in the `ad` library? (I don't want to autodifferentiate through this function.) I am using the [grad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad-4.3.6/docs/Numeric-AD.html#v:grad) function in this library.

If the library doesn't provide this feature, is there some way I can easily implement this functionality myself, perhaps by changing the definitions of leaf nodes in `ad` or by editing the dual numbers that presumably carry the numerical gradients?

Here's a concrete example of what I mean:

Say I have some function I want to take the gradient of, say `f(x, y) = x^2 + 3 * g(x, y)^2`. Then say that `g(x, y)` is a function whose definition is complicated, but whose gradient I've already calculated analytically and is quite simple. Thus, when I take `grad f` and evaluate it at a point `(x, y)`, I'd like to just plug in my custom gradient for `g`, instead of autodiffing through it: something like `my_nice_grad_of_g (x, y)`.

I see other autodiff libraries do provide this feature, for example [Stan](https://github.com/stan-dev/math/wiki/Adding-a-new-function-with-known-gradients) and [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RegisterGradient) both allow users to define gradients of a function.